# apt update gets stuck on Debian

Tags: debian, apt

I run Linux debs 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux.

`sudo apt update` fails with:

```
Get:26 http://debian.volia.net/debian stretch/main i386 Packages [7,069 kB]...        
Get:29 http://debian.volia.net/debian stretch/main Translation-en [5,388 kB]
Get:30 http://debian.volia.net/debian stretch/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,066 kB]
0% [Working]
```

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://debian.volia.net/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://debian.volia.net/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main


deb http://debian.volia.net/debian/ stretch-updates main    
deb-src http://debian.volia.net/debian/ stretch-updates main

deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ DISTRO main
```

Comment: So it's just stuck there?

Comment: Yes, each time on the same line. I've tried to change the mirrors, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I have never seen the "DEP-11 Metadata" part before. Do you have something strange in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`? (show us that file, by editing the question)

Comment: @Henrik added it.

Comment: @GAD3R Initially, that didn't help, but then I just commented out that line and it worked, asking to install apt-transport-https. After successful pass, I cuncommented it (with stretch) and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Please update the question so the `sources.list` match the output you show. As it is you're using different mirrors.

Comment: "DISTRO" is wrong (I checked the repository), please change that to "stretch" and stop messing with that. Furthermore your output still doesn't match the `sources.list` you show, the output mentions "linux.teamviewer.com" which is not in the `sources.list` you show. Do you have some files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that might cause this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86751/discussion-between-henrik-and-bord81).

Comment: Comment out voila.net sources and check if apt still works. If yes, then switch to a more stable debian repository.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The last entry of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is wrong:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ DISTRO main
```

`apt-get` is most likely stuck waiting to reach the directory `DISTRO` which does not exists.

It will probably receive several 404 error from the webserver and reach a timeout. But, the best way to fix this is just to remove the last line of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.